# Will objects heat up and become hidden at relativistic speed?

Tags: special-relativity, photons

Let us assume there is a mirror travelling at extremely relativistic speeds, perhaps few picometers away from speed of light, and let us assume we have a very thin detector which is very small perhaps few atom thick detector like so:

[image]

Now let us assume as the mirror passes us, we shoot a photon towards the mirror through the detector and say it hits the mirror however with the every-day intuition we would see the light reflect back immediately and so the detector would detect photon, however in this scenario we observe something different, as the time dilates at the speed the atoms  in side the mirror would take longer to reflect (emit photons back) the light, however in this "extra" time the photon takes the mirror would have moved slightly forward and so when the atom reflects the light back the photon would miss the detector due to the time dilation.

If my thought experiment is justified, does this mean that as the object approaches speed of light the object essentially becomes "invisible" as it takes longer and longer to reflect light back? This also could mean the object becomes becomes "hotter" and "hotter" due to energy of light being essentially "locked in" as it approaches light so before the object even approaches light the object it could basically heat up, however as it slows down the photons are released?

This should also imply at relativistic scales, photoelectric affect might not be true anymore as we can fire trillions of low energy photons at a given surface and then due to the atoms just absorbing rather than emitting back the photons would simply behave as though a high energy photon has hit it and would escape?

Comment: If an object melts in one frame, it must melt in all frames.  But you, or any other object, are (relatively) moving arbitrarily close to the speed of light in an infinity of inertial reference frames and still, you don't melt.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri I totally agree here, but keeping in mind we are firing the photon towards it, rather than it firing photons towards us so technically it must heat up and "melt" rather than us.

Comment: The photon just is. It doesn't matter that, from your point of view, you fired it at the mirror. The photon moves the same speed in every inertial reference frame. It's moving at c in your reference frame and moving at c in the mirror's reference frame. From the mirror's point of view, it could as well be stationary and you are moving away from it at nearly the speed of light. The mirror will see the photon as extremely red-shifted compared to the frequency you experience it at.